# discord.js players name and score request problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
 getOnlinePlayers() {
      return new Promise((send, err) => {
           axios.get(`http://query.li/api/csgo/185.198.75.5/27015`)
           .then(function(body) {
           let online = body.data.game.players;
           send(online);

           }).catch(function(error) {
           err(error);
           });
      })
 }
```

Hello friends, how can I print the name and score of the people in the players section from the site on the link in a single message?

Comment: add the message format that you want in your question

Comment: Name:
Score:
------------------------
Name:
Score:
------------------------
In this way, I want to print all active players in the players section of the site in one message.

Comment: Do you mean section as `object` for players?

Comment: It's simple just create an array with an iterator on your `players` and then concatinate all these items as the format that you want

Comment: I'm new to node.js, unfortunately I don't have excessive knowledge. Please help me. By the way, this is the part of the site I'm talking about ...
    "players": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "name": "| \u262c\u0e56\u06e3\u06dc\u01e4host\u0f3b |",
                "score": 20,
                "duration": 15213.8388671875
            },
            {
                "index": 0,
                "name": "VigneroN",
                "score": 2,
                "duration": 13411.525390625
            },

Answer (score 0):

If your players object has this format:

```
const players = [
  {
   name: 'John',
   score: 120
  },
  .
  .
  .
 ]
```

So the required message will be something like this:

```
const message = JSON.parse(players).map(player => {
   return `Name: ${player.name}\nScore: ${player.score}`;
}).join('\n--------\n');
```

Comment: thats not work i have (node:11356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined error :/
I'm making you try hard, my friend, sorry, but I've been going crazy since morning

Comment: please help me :(

Comment: use `JSON.parse(payers)` I think this will solve your issue

Comment: I fixed the data pull problem, but I can print all of them with foreach in one message, but not all players in one message.
I opened a current topic, can you look at this topic? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671431/discord-js-sendmessage-line-order-problem